# When the command / start is sent to the bot, the bot should delete the stickers sent to the group; but the bot does not work

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am built a telegram bot with the Python-Telegram-Bot framework.I added it to a group and admin the bot in the group.

bot codes:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters

updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def sticker_method(bot, update):
    update.message.delete()

def sticker_delete():
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, sticker_method))
    updater.start_polling() 
    updater.idle()

def sticker_undelete():
    dispatcher.remove_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, sticker_method))

start_command = CommandHandler('start', sticker_delete)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)

notdelete_command = CommandHandler('notdelete', sticker_undelete)
dispatcher.add_handler(notdelete_command)

updater.start_polling() 
updater.idle()
```

After the group creator sends the bot command `/start`, the bot will delete the stickers that the group members send to the group.

And also, when the group creator command `/notdelete` send it to the bot, the bot should not delete the stickers that members send to the group.

But the bot does not work; when the group creator sends the group command `/start` to the bot, it will not delete the bot stickers that are sent to the group.

What do you think the problem is that the bot does not work ???

The codes do not give any error, but as I said, the bot does not work.

Comment: Do you try to delete past sticker messages or sticker messages that will come after the creator send the 'start' command? Because right now it looks like you want to do the second. Also, you don't need `.start_polling()` and `.idle()` twice. I would try a different approach: If creator send command `start`, save boolean START = True. If creator send `notdelete` set START = False. Then move `MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, sticker_method))` out of the method, so that all stickers get filtered and check in that method if START = True. If so, remove the current message

Comment: @Endogen I do not understand what you are saying, because I can not read or write English well, please modify the code with your own method.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure it's **supergroup**, not normal group

Your bot need Delete Message permission, and Privacy Mode should be disabled.

Bots can't get message list, they can only receive that when someone send it, so you need to log Enable/Disable state to your own database, and delete Sticker when received new message.

Comment: group is a supergroup and the bot admin in the supergroup

Comment: your answer is a false

Comment: @SeanYour answer is a false