# the telegram bot does not work;in your opinion, why does the bot not work?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm building a telegram bot with the Python-Telegram-Bot framework.To test the bot, I added it to a super group and I got the bot into the Super group **Admin**.

My code for creating a bot:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters

updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def sticker_method(bot, update):
    update.message.delete()

def main():
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, sticker_method))



dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', main))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

I want to create the bot that when `/start` command send to the bot, then the bot delete the stickers that the members send to the super group.that means as `/start` of a command, when the creator super group(I) sends a bot , the bot should delete the stickers that are sent to the super group.

But the bot does not work!And do not give any error!

In your opinion, why does the bot not work?

Answer (score 0):

Is this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46278702/5201431)?

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46279046/5201431), that is impossible.

> Your bot need have Delete Message permission, and Privacy Mode should be disabled.
>
> Bots can't get message list, they can only receive that when someone sends it, so you need to log Enable/Disable state to your own database and delete Sticker when received new messages.

Comment: I have seen lightsabers cutting steel and stone, but still it seems pretty hard.